# Can I follow where the ferry between Vaasa and Uumaja (Vasa and Umeå) is?

Tags: ferries, sweden, finland, ships

The ferry from Vaasa to Uumaja has turned back due to bad weather. Is there a way of following where it is, expected arrival time and other such information?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can follow many vessels worldwide through vessel finder websites, such as [vesselfinder.com](https://www.vesselfinder.com/) or [marinetraffic.com](https://www.marinetraffic.com/).  The websites are free for basic use, not unlike airline tracking websites.  This will allow you to see where the vessel is right now.

Specifically, you can follow the [WASA EXPRESS](https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/shipid:5586/mmsi:230636000/imo:8000226/vessel:WASA_EXPRESS).  It is apparently due in Holmsund next at 2018-11-29 12:30 LT (UTC +1), having left Vaasa at  2018-11-29 09:03 LT (UTC +2).  I don't know how quickly marinetraffic will pick up in case plans change, but when it has physically turned around you should be able to tell from the live tracking soon enough.

**Edit:** According to [a comment by vidarlo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/126460/can-i-follow-where-the-ferry-between-vaasa-and-uumaja-vasa-and-ume%c3%a5-is/126461?noredirect=1#comment313642_126461), *Destination is sent as part of AIS messages, so Marinetraffic (and other sites) will pick up as soon as the bridge changes destination on their AIS instruments.*

Comment: The due date is in the past and it can indeed be seen that the ship has turned around. Thanks.

Comment: Destination is sent as part of AIS messages, so Marinetraffic (and other sites) will pick up as soon as the bridge changes destination on their AIS instruments.